# How to prove that a vector space is the direct sum of the T-invariant subspaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional complex vector space $V$.

(a) Let $\alpha$ be an eigenvalue of $T$, and let $V_{\lambda}$ be the set of generalized eigenvectors, together with the zero vector. Prove that $V_{\lambda}$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$.

(b) Prove that $V$ is the direct sum of its generalized eigenspaces.

This is a problem from Artin, chp 4. I've understood how to prove part a), but I can't figure out how to show it for all generalised eigenspaces.